# CreateFile() always fails

Tags: c, windows, string, winapi, unicode

```
char    tempFilename[256];
wchar_t filename[512];

fprintf(stdout, "Please enter file name/path: \n");
getchar();
fgets(tempFilename, 255, stdin);

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, tempFilename, -1, filename, strlen(tempFilename)*2);

if((hReadFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ , 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "File could not be opened, make sure name is under 256 chars. Error Code - %d.\n", GetLastError());
    return (0);
}
```

I have checked that MultiByteToWideChar() succeeds.

Infact I have also tried path like C:\users\user_name\desktop\test.txt instead of  C:\users\user_name\desktop\test.txt

i use following to convert \ to \\

```
while(temp < len )
{
    filename1[cntr1] = tempFilename[temp];
    cntr1 += 1;
    if(tempFilename[temp] == '\\')
    {
        filename1[cntr1] = '\\';
        cntr1 += 1;
    }
    temp += 1;
}
```

this works till \ to \\. 
Where am I going wrong..?

Comment: I'm guessing that filename has a CRLF in it.

Comment: I'm not sure with what purpose you 'convert \ to \\'.

Comment: What is the `getchar();` for? It seems to eat up the first character entered.

Comment: If it fails, what's the error code?

Comment: @martin, yes it had. tht was the prblm. SO error code was 123.. syntax of the filename.

Comment: @alk fgets() doesn't wait for the input.

Comment: If `fgets()` returns immediately then there still had been a `'\n'` in `stdin`'s input buffer prior to the call to `fgets()`.

Comment: give me single reason why my que was downvoted? As stackoverflow has given facility to users to click somewhere.. do not just click it, give proper reasons. (at least say you hate me :D)

Comment: It's okay to augment the question with extra information but not to change the essence of it in a way that invalidates answers. That should be done with a different question since it really _is_ a different question. I didn't downvote you (in fact I just upvoted since I dislike drive-bys and you _did_ seem to put in the necessary research) but that may well be the reason why it happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print out `filename` before you try to use it. Nine times out of ten, a simple debug output like that will show you the exact problem.

And print it out with delimiters so that you can see if you have a newline in there:

```
printf ("[%s]\n", filename);
```

(or equivalent means, such as using `wprintf`).

If there's a newline, you'll see:

```
[myfile.txt
]
```

instead of:

```
[myfile.txt]
```

If you get a string where you want the newline stripped, you can use something like:

```
int slen = strlen (filename);
if ((slen > 0) && (filename[slen-1] == '\n'))
    filename[slen-1] = '\0';
```

(again, or equivalent, such as using `wcslen`).

And on another matter, you shouldn't need to replace `\` with `\\` if the input is coming from the user. The escaping is only required in the C source code itself.

And, one last thing, I'm not *entirely* certain why you're calling `getchar()` before `fgets()` - you're likely to lose the first character of whatever you're typing in.

Comment: A virtual extra +1 for "*... print it out with delimiters ...*"! :-)

Comment: Thanks. You were right onto it. please edit answer to wprintf(...) and wcslen(...).